# Xamarin Android (Mono for Android) Split Action Bar

Tags: c#, android, mono, android-actionbar, xamarin

I created an ActionBar, but now need to split it for an other button at the bottom.
I know how it works in Java but i need to do it with Xamarin in C#.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Ok i got it.

Put this in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application android:label="MyAwesomeApp" android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"></application>
```

Answer (score 0):

this will also work, add it to the activity 
UiOptions = Android.Content.PM.UiOptions.SplitActionBarWhenNarrow